# Is it possible to convert a 30 second clip of an .mp3 to .wav via the command line?

Tags: command-line, mplayer

Is it possible to convert a 30 second clip of an .mp3 to .wav in Ubuntu terminal? For example if I had an .mp3 that was 3:00 minutes long, would I be able to create a 30 second clip from 0:45-1:15?

I'm able to convert the entire song using mplayer in Ubuntu.

```
mplayer \
  -quiet \
  -vo null \
  -vc dummy \
  -ao pcm:waveheader:file="output.wav" "input.mp3"
```

http://en.linuxreviews.org/HOWTO_Convert_audio_files

I'm open to suggestions using mplayer, LAME, mpg123, mpg321 or other encoders!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try

```
ffmpeg -ss 45 -t 30 -i file.mp3 output.wav
```

(start at 45s, length 30s)

More info:
http://linux.die.net/man/1/ffmpeg

Answer (score 3):

Use that same mplayer command and add options

```
-ss 45 -endpos 30
```

Comment: Hey David,  Thanks so much for answering the question even though a "best answer" was selected.  I appreciate it.

Comment: No problem. I just think support forums should be complete, you know, for future archaeologists.